# How to create box plot based on min and max alone

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

In ggplot, we can create a bar plot by specifying the colum in the data frame that has the height of the bars

```
library("ggplot2")
library(plyr)
mm <- ddply(mtcars, "cyl", summarise, mmpg = mean(mpg))
ggplot(mm, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mmpg)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

However, I cannot figure out how to make a similar plot that both top AND bottom of the bars are specified.
For instance using the data below

```
df <- read.table(text = " id  min  max 
    Sp1     8.5          13.2     
 Sp2     11.7          14.5     
 Sp3     14.7          17.7     ", header=TRUE)
```

We would get a plot closely resembling this:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `geom_crossbar`:

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_crossbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max, x = id, y = min),
                fill = "blue", fatten = 0)
```

[image]

Comment: I would add `fatten=0` to the `geom_crossbar` call to effectively get rid of the "mid" line which is making the bottom border thicker.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `geom_boxplot` if you precise all the `aes`.

```
df$med = 0.5*(df$min+df$max)
ggplot(df, 
       aes(x=id, ymin=min, lower=min,fill=id ,
           middle=`med`, upper=max, ymax=max)) +
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
```

[image]