# How to illustrate different ranges on an x-axis?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2

How to illustrate different ranges on an x-axis?

In a previous post ([How to create box plot based on min and max alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21560861/how-to-create-box-plot-based-on-min-and-max-alone)) it was described how to create a box plot based on min and max alone.  It is close to what I am looking for.
I am looking in a project at different ranges on x-axis - and would like to visualize if they are overlapping or not. To me this would be the plots shown in the named post rotated by 90 degrees.

My data look like this:

```
df_ART5
       ID    tart    stop
1 Exon 01 3659736 3660023
2 Exon 02 3659736 3660149
3 Exon 03 3660233 3660265
4 Exon 04 3660872 3661025
5 Exon 05 3660872 3661601
6 Exon 06 3661076 3661601
7 Exon 07 3663036 3663094
8 Exon 08 3663036 3663546
9 Exon 09 3663408 3663546
```

As an output I would like to have something like this:

[image]
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

there's a [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/boxplot_demo.html) which provides different layouts, including horizontal ranges. I've condensed this example to the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# fake up some data
spread = np.random.rand(50) * 100
center = np.ones(25) * 50
flier_high = np.random.rand(10) * 100 + 100
flier_low = np.random.rand(10) * -100
data = np.concatenate((spread, center, flier_high, flier_low), 0)

# horizontal boxes
plt.figure()
plt.boxplot(data, 0, 'rs', False)

plt.show()
```

From the [pyplot API](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html): the 4th or `vert` parameter controls the orientation

> vert : bool, default = True
>
> If True (default), makes the boxes vertical. If False, makes horizontal boxes.